# redirecting urls with question mark

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect:
http://www.mydomain.com/myfolder/?5/my-page
to:
http://www.mydomain.com/myfolder/?5/page

a simple redirect in .htaccess doesn't seem to work:

```
Redirect 301 /myfolder/?5/my-page http://www.mydomain.com/myfolder/?5/page
```

I've searched around and found it must be because of the question mark.
So after some searching I tried this:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^my-page
 RewriteRule ^my-page http://www.mydomain.com/myfolder/?5/page [L,R=301]
```

Which totally doesn't work either. I think I won't be able to solve it myself, and would like to ask if somebody else could lead me on a better path?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The query string is *everything* after the ? so this would be `5/my-page` and not `my-page` in this example, so the rewrite directive which match your URI would be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^5/my-page$
RewriteRule ^myfolder/$ myfolder/?5/page? [L,R=301]
```

You need the `?` in the replacement pattern because the engine would append the existing query string without this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer - [Removing trailing question mark with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165287/removing-trailing-question-mark-with-htaccess/15680832#15680832)

to redirect from like this:

```
http://site.com/index.php?blaaa=123&idd=999
```

to

```
http://site.com/page/
```